# Opencv,c++-Is there an alternative to HSV filtering for obtaining a binary image of a person?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.0

I'm making a gesture recognition program in c++ with opencv. So before recognising the gesture, I need to first obtain a filtered binary image of the person(specifically hands). Most tutorials suggest using HSV colour filtering. But this method is very inefficient because the colour of the person has to be different from the background. So I searched more and found an alternative called background substraction. But only backgroundsubtracterMOG2 exists and there is always an overlap between the previously filtered frame and the current one. Is there any way to eliminate this overlap or is there a more efficient way to filter the binary image?

Comment: 1) the title doesn't reflect the question. 2) habe you initialized the bkg model without the person?

Comment: Thanks for 1). When you say initialize the bkg model without the person, do you mean filtering the image without any movement in the image(i.e. no change in pixels)?

Comment: Get in the camera view 10 seconds after you start bkg subtraction mog